# Most efficient way to sort a multidimensional array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, web, multidimensional-array

I am looking for the most efficient way to sort a multidimensional array in php.I want to sort the array by the value `name` in `[result][index][kl][0]`. What is the fastest way to do this? My array has like 100 elements.
My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[jsonrpc] => 2.0
[id] => req-002
[result] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type] => subst
                [lsid] => 11
                [date] => 20150209
                [startTime] => 955
                [endTime] => 1040
                [kl] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 29
                                [name] => S12UB
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [type] => subst
                [lsid] => 11
                [date] => 20150209
                [startTime] => 1045
                [endTime] => 1130
                [kl] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 29
                                [name] => S12UB
                            )

                    )

            )
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a user-defined sort function, like [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) along with [`strcmp`](http://php.net/strcmp):

```
function compareByName($a, $b) {
    // the strcmp returns a numeric value above or below 0 depending on the comparison
    return strcmp($a['k1'][0]['name'], $b['k1'][0]['name']);
}
```

Then, assuming your multi-dimensional array is named `$array`, replace the multi-dimensional array `$array['result']` with the newly sorted array:

```
$array['result'] = usort($array['result'], 'compareByName');
```

The documentation for the `usort` and `strcmp` should be self-explanatory for understanding how the code works above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = uasort($result, function($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a['kl'][0]['name'], $b['kl'][0]['name']);
});
```